# When node.js goes down, how can I bring it back up automatically?

Tags: node.js

Since node is basically a single process, when something goes terribly wrong, the whole application dies.

I now have a couple of apps built on express and I am using some manual methods to prevent extended downtimes ( process.on('uncaughtException') and a custom heartbeat monitor ).

Any suggestions from the community?
Best-practices? Frameworks?

Thanks!
A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like [`forever`](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever)

or use [`supervisor`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor).

Just `npm link` and then `sudo supervisor server.js`.

These types of libraries also support hot reloading. There are some which you use from the command line and they run node services as sub processes for you. There are others which expect you to write your code to reload itself.

Ideally what you want to move towards a full blown load balancer which is failure safe. If a single node proccess in your load balancer crashes you want it to be quietly restarted and all the connections and data rescued.

Personally I would recommend `supervisor` for development (It's written by isaacs!) and a full blown load balancer (either nginx or node) for your real production server.

Of course your already running multiple node server processes in parallel because you care about scaling across multiple cores right ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever).

"A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously (i.e. forever)"

Just install it with npm

```
npm install forever
```

and type

```
forever start app.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever) module.

Comment: After 11 years ;) new link for [forever](https://github.com/foreversd/forever) 
But the official page encourage to use now [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ubuntu you can use upstart (which is installed by default).

$ cat /etc/init/my_app.conf

> description "my_app"
>   author "me"
>
> start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0) stop on
>   shutdown
>
> respawn
>
> exec sh -c "env NODE_ENV=production node /path/myapp/app.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1"

"respawn" mean that the app will be restarted if it dies.

To start the app

> start my_app

For other commands

> man initctl

Answer (score 1):

I'll strongly recommend `forever` too. I used it yesterday and its a breeze:

1. Install `npm install forever`
2. Start your app `forever start myapp.js`
3. Check if its working `forever list`

Try killing your app :

1. `ps`
2. Get your myapp.js pid and run `kill <pid`
3. run `forever list` and you'll see it's running again

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Fugue, a library for node.js similar to Spark or Unicorn:

https://github.com/pgte/fugue

Fugue can manage any node.js server type, not just web servers, and it's set up and configured as a node.js script, not a CLI command, so normal node.js build & deployment toolchains can use it.