# Node.js setup for easy deployment and updating

Tags: node.js, deployment, updates

We're currently developing a website (TYPO3 under Apache) for a customer that is supported by a node.js/socket.io application that provides realtime updates to the content served from the CMS.

As this is our first node.js project I don't have any best practices to go by when it comes to 'the perfect setup' so I've spent some time researching deployment techniques.

A couple of questions remain for me to achieve a good setup which:

1. **Is easy for the customer to deploy**. This is very important because our website will be integrated in their 'live' TYPO3 installation which serves an abundance of websites and is running on servers which aren't managed by the customer but another (centralized) organization which makes support calls and server changes a slow process.
2. **Should be easy to update.** As mentioned requesting restarts and making server changes is a slow process, so idealy the node installation should restart / update when it receives changes that are pushed onto the live installion using `git`.

**Deployment**

The [general consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681067/how-to-deploy-node-js) seems to be to use `forever` when it comes to deploying node applications to keep them running. I've tested `forever`, and it seems to work fine when installed by `npm install forever -g` (global). This would require external assistance to globally install on the live environment though, so I'd prefer to have it running from the application's `node_modules` directory, but I haven't been able to create a solid wrapper to do so.

Additionally, `forever` works fine, but it has to be started manually. What would be the best approach to ensure that it gets started on server boot and keeps running?

- A simple `init.d` script?
- Writing a watchdog wrapper?
- A TYPO3 scheduler task that checks `forever` status?

**Rapid development / Restart on update**

We're currently still in the development stage of the project and every time I make changes to the node.js application I manually restart `node` or `forever`. This works, but is far from ideal.
There are several smaller `npm` modules that check for file modifications and restart `node` upon detected changes, like:

- [Nodemon](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/12/nodejs-rapid-development-nodemon/)
- [Node.js Supervisor](http://fgnass.posterous.com/nodejs-supervisor)
- [Bounce](https://github.com/weepy/bounce)
- [Nodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929366/813718) (which doesn't require restarting node, so might be easier to combine with `forever`)
- [Up](https://github.com/LearnBoost/up)

Does anyone have experience with any of these?

**Update: Why don't you just use Cluster?**

The [Cluster module](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster) provides similar functionality through the [reload](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/docs/reload.html) mechanism, but [doesn't work with Node 0.5+](https://github.com/kriszyp/multi-node/issues/14). The [core Cluster module (Node 0.6+)](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) that replaced it doesn't have all these features but only provides clustering. Which in turn [doesn't play well with socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster/issues/95). At least [not without using Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395407/using-socket-io-with-cluster) (which is a problem for us, because we can't force another prereq service to the customer).

--

Obviously I'm trying to find the most stable solution that combines an update-restarter with `forever` before handing over the project to the customer and I'm really hoping anyone has produced a proven combination of techniques.

Comment: and to anyone else thinking of Cluster: it has not been updated in the last three years.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Combining all knowledge gathered (Big thanks to [Julian Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309986/julian-knight) for the ideas) and methods tested in the past week, I've decided to settle for the deployment solution described below (I thought I'd be nice to share to help others with comparable questions):

Auto-restarting on script errors ***and*** automatic reloading on script changes is handled by  [**forever**](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/), as it also includes a script watch, as long as Forever is spawned from within a node.js script.

To do so, I've added a `server.js` to launch the `app.js` script we actually want to run:

**server.js**

```
var forever = require('forever'),
    child = new(forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
        'silent': false,
        'pidFile': 'pids/app.pid',
        'watch': true,
        'watchDirectory': '.',      // Top-level directory to watch from.
        'watchIgnoreDotFiles': true, // whether to ignore dot files
        'watchIgnorePatterns': [], // array of glob patterns to ignore, merged with contents of watchDirectory + '/.foreverignore' file
        'logFile': 'logs/forever.log', // Path to log output from forever process (when daemonized)
        'outFile': 'logs/forever.out', // Path to log output from child stdout
        'errFile': 'logs/forever.err'
    });
child.start();
forever.startServer(child);
```

This watches all files in the application directory for changes and restarts the script running in `forever`as soon as one changes. Because the logs and pidfile are in subdirectories of the application, those have to be ignored from the file watch, or the script will loop restarts:

**.foreverignore**

```
pids/**
logs/**
```

To make this all start on system boot and enabling us to easily control the service using `start node-app`and `stop node-app` we use [Ubuntu's Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).
I've combined two examples ([this](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/) and [this](http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/) one) into one that does the job quite well:

**/etc/init/node-app.conf**

```
# This is an upstart (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script
# to run the node.js server on system boot and make it
# manageable with commands such as
# 'start node-app' and 'stop node-app'
#
# This script is to be placed in /etc/init to work with upstart.
#
# Internally the 'initctl' command is used to manage:
# initctl help
# initctl status node-app
# initctl reload node-app
# initctl start node-app

description "node.js forever server for node-app"
author      "Remco Overdijk <remco@maxserv.nl>"
version "1.0"

expect fork

# used to be: start on startup
# until we found some mounts weren't ready yet while booting:

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env HOME=/home/user/node-app-dir

script
    # Not sure why $HOME is needed, but we found that it is:
    export HOME=$HOME
    chdir $HOME
    exec /usr/local/bin/node server.js > logs/node.log &
end script

#post-start script
#   # Optionally put a script here that will notifiy you node has (re)started
#   # /root/bin/hoptoad.sh "node.js has started!"
#end script
```

As [Kevin wisely mentions in his article](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/) it's unwise to run node as root, so we'll change that to `exec sudo -u www-data /usr/local/bin/node` when we move to new servers next week.

So, `forever` gets started automatically by `node server.js` which gets launched by `upstart`, and monitors for crashes and file changes, keeping the entire setup running as long as we want.

I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I just tried this and I'm not able to get it working, can you help me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639828/nodejs-and-forever-monitoring-and-restarting-app

Comment: I used this same startup script and when using Upstart on Amazon Linux (v 0.6.5) the upstart script would hang, especially noticable with `sudo start node-app`. I had to remove `expect fork` because my node process did not fork, so Upstart was waiting for a SIGCHLD that would never come. Great answer though, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Since my last answer is for the future! Here are some other links to assist:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/274857/how-to-use-node-js-as-a-production-web-server
- http://www.slideshare.net/the_undefined/nodejs-best-practices-10428790 (see slide 35)
- http://www.slideshare.net/the_undefined/nodejs-in-production (slides 31 to the end)
- [When node.js goes down, how can I bring it back up automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668126/when-node-js-goes-down-how-can-i-bring-it-back-up-automatically)

There doesn't yet seem to be a perfect answer but there are plenty of people running production Node instances. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort in helping to solve this! Your first link got me on track to the `upstart` solution I've gone for in the end (see my own answer for the combined solution). Greatly appreciate your research!

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't answer more directly. Please do mark your own answer as *The* answer though, you are encouraged to do that, it is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

You might be better off, for production use, to look at something like [Cluster](https://github.com/learnboost/cluster). You might not want the cluster features but it also includes other production features such as zero downtime restarts, logging, workers, etc.

As you say, Forever is OK for testing but doesn't really have what it takes for production use.

I seem to vaguely remember that Cluster or something similar may be adopted into Node itself come v0.7

Comment: That sounded like the perfect solution, but unfortunately it's not going to work. [The core cluster module that ships with Node 0.6+](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) is pretty bare bones and doesn't come with all the fancy features we're _actually_ interested in. Futhermore, [the 'old' module](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster) doesn't [work with Node 0.5+](https://github.com/kriszyp/multi-node/issues/14). Too bad, but this isn't going to be the solution. Thanks a lot for suggesting though!

Comment: Doh! Sorry, I've not yet put any Node.js into production so I missed this. One of the reasons I've not yet committed to Node is its clear lack of maturity. Hopefully 0.7 will go some way towards fixing this but there is a vast deficit on documentation that also needs plugging.