# centos+nodejs+forever(startstop)

Tags: bash, node.js, centos, forever

Good day i have some problem with forever start\stop script.

CentOS 6.2 
kernel 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 
nodejs v0.6.19
npm v 1.1.24
forever@0.9.2

i create nologin user for running my script

**/etc/passwd** 

node:x:501:501::/usr/sbin/nologin:/bin/bash:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin/forever:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin

i create script and named hello2.js

```
  #!/bin/bash
echo "aight"
```

and try to running

```
  [max@localhost Desktop]$ forever start hello2.js
    info: Forever processing file: hello2.js
    [max@localhost Desktop]$ forever list
    info: Forever processes running
    data: uid command script forever pid logfile uptime
    data: [0] n4EB node hello2.js 2675 2728 /home/max/.forever/n4EB.log 0:0:0:0.130
```

Everything all right. And the next i create start-stop script for hello2.js and named him node

===========================

```
#!/bin/bash

#proccessname: node

USER=node
PWD=node
node=node
forever=forever

start() {

         forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log /home/max/Desktop/hello2.js

            }

stop(){

      /usr/local/bin/forever stopall
     }

  restart() {
   stop
   start
    }
    status(){
    /usr/local/bin/forever list
    }

    #see how we were called
    case "$1" in
    start)
    start
    ;;
    stop)
    stop
    ;;
    restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
    status)
    status
    ;;
    *)
    echo $ "usage $0 {start | stop | status | restart}"
    exit 1
    esac
    exit 0
```

=========================================
made it executable.

And the next i want to look how this working

```
[max@localhost Desktop]$ ./node
$ usage ./node {start | stop | status | restart}

[max@localhost Desktop]$ ./node start
info: Forever processing file: /home/max/Desktop/hello2.js

[max@localhost Desktop]$ ./node status
**info: No forever processes running**
```

But

```
[max@localhost Desktop]$ forever start hello2.js
info: Forever processing file: hello2.js
[max@localhost Desktop]$ forever list
info: Forever processes running
data: uid command script forever pid logfile uptime
data: [0] n4EB node hello2.js 2675 2728 /home/max/.forever/n4EB.log 0:0:0:0.130
[max@localhost Desktop]$
```

where my mistake?

Comment: Did you try `ps ax | grep -Ei "node|forever"` after using your init script to start?

Comment: You might take a look at my solution using `upstart` (which is supported on CentOS I believe): http://stackoverflow.com/q/11084279/813718. It might make the entire process a lot easier and enables you to use additional features which are only available when using `forever` from within Node.

Comment: [max@localhost Desktop]$ ps ax | grep -Ei "node|forever"
 2675 ?        Ss    28:23 node /usr/local/bin/forever start hello2.js
11222 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep -Ei node|forever
30613 ?        S      0:03 gedit /home/max/Desktop/node

Comment: Is it possible that your start is using a different forever binary? Status and stop use the full path whereas your start does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nohup forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log /home/max/Desktop/hello2.js &
```