# Upstart script for node.js app

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart

I'm having trouble starting an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script.

Here's the script (app.conf in /etc/init/)

```
description "node.js server"
author      "kvz"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
   # We found $HOME is needed. Without it, we ran into problems
   export HOME="/root"

   exec sudo -u /usr/local/bin/node \
                /var/www/vhosts/travelseguro.com/node/app.js \
                2>&1 >> /var/log/node.log
end script
```

When I run `sudo start app`, I get:

> start: Unknown job: app

How can I make this work?

Comment: I copied your script into `/etc/init/app.conf` and it worked for me (started a process and created the log file.) Are you sure the file is in the correct place with (`ls -Al /etc/init/app.conf`)?
Also, what version of Upstart (`start --version`) and what OS?

Comment: Yes im sure its there..
Upstart 0.3.9
Ubuntu 8.04.4

Comment: I used nodejitsu forever and it works very well i wanted upstart because i wanted to have it as a service its a simple very small client support chat so.. no big deal by using forever.

Comment: Try a symlink in /etc/init.d something like ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job app.

Comment: You have to reload configuration info for upstart. Use "sudo initctl reload-configuration" for this. I wrote detailed answer below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same problem running on the latest Amazon (AWS) linux which is Redhat based.

I have my [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) file in `/etc/init` called `node.conf` and when I ran `sudo start node` I would get a similar error to you `start: Unknown job: node`.

It turns out that the job won't start if there's an error in your `.conf` file.  So I started out by commenting out all the lines and slowly building up to find the error.  **The error message isn't very clear and makes it look like upstart can't find your conf file.**

Tailing your '/var/log/messages' will help you debug as Upstart logs to there (It may be somewhere different on Ubuntu.  Mine said `init: /etc/init/node-upstart.conf:8: Unknown stanza` which helped me get to the bottom of it.  In my particular case I was declaring variables incorrectly.

See on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30796/upstart-script-doesnt-start) for a similar thread.

Here's my *edited* working script:

```
<!-- language: lang-sh -->
#!upstart
# using upstart http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html and node forever  https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/  
# to run server
# redhat has additional sudo restrictions, you must comment out 'Default requiretty' from /etc/sudoers
#startup monitoring script derived from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084279/node-js-setup-for-easy-deployment-and-updating

description "node.js server"
author      "jujhar"
env PROGRAM_NAME="node"
env FULL_PATH="/home/httpd/buto-middleman/public"
env FILE_NAME="forever.js"
env NODE_PATH="/usr/local/bin/node"
env USERNAME="springloops"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"  
    export NODE_ENV=staging #development/staging/production

    echo $$ > /var/run/$PROGRAM_NAME.pid
    cd $FULL_PATH        
    #exec sudo -u $USERNAME $NODE_PATH $FULL_PATH/$FILE_NAME >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
    exec $NODE_PATH $FULL_PATH/$FILE_NAME >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/$PROGRAM_NAME.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log
end script
```

-- **Edit 2013-06-01** --

If you're on Centos or Amazon Linux like me, take a look at this [init.d script](https://gist.github.com/nariyu/1211413).

-- **Edit 2013-10-14** --

Here's a [link to a gist](https://gist.github.com/jujhars13/6994349) of an init.d script that I actually use in production on Amazon Linux(Redhat Based).  I simply keep it in my project under an `init.d` folder and then symlink to it in the `/etc/init.d` folder and now it's a daemon/service!

-- **Edit 2014-06-05** --

Check out this awesome [blog artcile](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/06/02/node-js-in-production/?utm_source=nodeweekly&utm_medium=email) by [Jeff Dickey](https://twitter.com/dickeyxxx) on Node.js in production using [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) which is much cleaner and easier than all the stuff we've been doing here (IMHO).  He also uses Ansible to control his cluster (which I love) but you don't have to go that far if you're not ready.

Comment: Your code doesn't allow to run the app under unprivileged user (your code doesn't work). See my working example below. It doesn't make any sense to use systemd on Ubuntu. Upstart allows to do whatever you need include delays a start of node.js until mongodb or other services will be started.

Answer (score 7):

After a few attempts I implemented working .conf file for upstart which works as a service with automatic start after reboot and restart (respawn) in case of crash. Also it can start my app with unprivileged user permissions. The name of the file is /etc/init/my-app.conf.

To start / stop service please use

```
sudo start my-app / sudo stop my-app
```

If you have an error like

```
start: Unknown job: my-app
```

exec the following command

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

My /etc/init/my-app.conf file:

```
#my-app                                                                           
description "node.js my-app website"                                                  
env FULL_PATH="/home/myuser/app.prod/app"                                              
env NODE_PATH="/usr/bin/node"                                                     


start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]                                            
stop on [!2345]                                                                   

script                                                                            
    export HOME="/root"                                                           
    export NODE_ENV=production                                                    
    echo $$ > /var/run/my-app.pid                                                 
    cd $FULL_PATH        
    #Use exec below if you want to launch it under myuser, 
    #don't forget to create /var/log/my-app.sys.log with appropriate permissions
    #exec sudo -u myuser sh -c "$NODE_PATH server.js >> /var/log/my-app.sys.log 2>&1" 
    exec $NODE_PATH server.js >> /var/log/my-app.sys.log 2>&1                     
end script                                                                        

pre-start script                                                                  
    echo "[`date`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/my-app.sys.log                     
end script                                                                        

pre-stop script                                                                   
    rm /var/run/my-app.pid                                                        
    echo "[`date`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/my-app.sys.log                     
end script                                                                        

#uncomment respawn if you want to restart your service in case of crash
#respawn                                                                          
#respawn limit 50 30
```

I do recommend to uncomment respawn after you will make sure that everything works ok.

**UPDATE**

I improved my script (please keep in mind that it works not under root but  under regular user **zn** ):

```
#znapi.conf                                                                    
description "node.js zn api"                                        

env FULL_PATH="/home/zn/app.prod"                          
env NODE_PATH="/usr/bin/node"                                  
env LOG="/var/log/znapi.log"
env PIDFILE="/var/run/znapi.pid"

# Start up when the system hits any normal runlevel, and 
#start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]     
#start when mongod started
start on started mongod

# shuts down when the system goes to shutdown or reboot.
stop on runlevel [06]                                                              

respawn
respawn limit 50 5

pre-start script                                                    
    # check that log file exist or create it
    test -f $LOG || { touch $LOG; chown zn:zn $LOG; }

    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date`] (sys) Starting" >> $LOG            
end script                                                          

script                                                                       
    export NODE_ENV=production
    exec start-stop-daemon --start -m -p $PIDFILE -c zn -d $FULL_PATH -x server.js >> $LOG 2>&1
end script                                                                   

pre-stop script                                                              
    rm $PIDFILE                                                   
    echo "[`date`] (sys) Stopping" >> $LOG                    
end script
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Roman, I used it for my server. However, when running as a different user using `exec sudo -u`, environment variables exported above will not be set. I solved it by running `exec sudo -u myuser sh- c "PORT=3000 SOME_VAR=SOME_VALUE $NODE_PATH server.js [...]" but I'm wondering whether there's a way to get the env variables to automatically follow into the shell for myuser?

Comment: @JHH Please try the improved version of my script