# NodeJS and Forever (monitoring and restarting app)

Tags: node.js, monitor, forever

I'm trying to setup `forever` and `NodeJS` to monitor&restart my app and also keep it running when exits. Currently I have this:

```
var forever = require("forever-monitor");

var child = new(forever.Monitor)('main.js', {
    'silent': false,
    'pidFile': '../pids/app.pid',
    'sourceDir': '.',
    'watch': true,
    'watchDirectory': '.',
    'watchIgnoreDotFiles': null,
    'watchIgnorePatterns': null,
    'logFile': '../logs/forever.log',
    'outFile': '../logs/forever.out',
    'errFile': '../logs/forever.err'
});

child.start();
```

Which starts my app just fine but it doesn't restart it when I make changes in the file. Is there some option that I'm missing?

EDIT:
After digging into the problem I found that the file change is detected actually, it's just that the process isn't restarted.
I'm looking at line ~317 - Monitor.prototype.kill (in monitor.js) but everything looks like it should work.

EDIT:
I managed to fix the issue. It's a bug in the library's code. Check here: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor/issues/27

Comment: Just note that people who need Forever likely care about stability and fault tolerance, which usually means not running a Windows machine to serve a web app. Might explain why you're not seeing a lot of responses here or on the github issue.

Comment: I won't go the OS-trolling way. Anyways, I didn't say I'm using Windows XP for production. I just said I'm using it. What's the point of NodeJS being multios of the standard answer for everything is "use Linux"?

Comment: it's more cynicism than trolling. you gotta know these devs are *not* investing much of their valuable time in testing on windows 7 (let alone windows XP). I just got done a nodejs app that's meant to run on windows because that's what my client is gonna use, and progress to fix issues on windows in these node packages is significantly slower.  Anyway, people use Forever in production web apps. If you use a closed source OS to run your web app in production, **you're probably doing it wrong**. there certainly may be exceptions but node is a distinctly unixy thing.

Comment: @StevenLu "Anyway, people use Forever in production web apps." Can you please elaborate and/or cite sources? Do you really think Forever is mature enough for use in production?

Comment: I don't think it's hard to come up with examples: [here](http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/running-a-node-js-web-site-in-production-a-beginners-guide), [here](http://blog.evantahler.com/blog/production-deployment-with-node-js-clusters.html)...

Sorry about coming off sounding self-righteous. It is just my opinion that the general stability and worthiness of MS's closed source stack is lacking. Hence my urging you, in particular if you want to use node, to switch to Linux, if you care about things like uptime.

Answer (score 2):

nodemon and forever are a pain to get running consistently. I would try using a shell script first. If you are on linux, just place a monitornode file in /etc/cron.d

```
*/1 * * * * root  /var/www/nodejs/monitornode.sh
```

and have a script somewhere on your machine

Try this if you are getting started, create a file /var/www/nodejs/monitornode.sh and chmod +x :

```
#!/bin/sh

TT_NODE="node /var/www/nodejs/node.js"

# NODEJS Watcher
if [ -z `pgrep -f -x "$TT_NODE"` ] 
then
    echo "Starting $TT_NODE."
    cmdNODE="$TT_NODE >> /var/www/logs/node.log &"
    eval $cmdNODE
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `nodemon` package to do the whole "reload on file change" thing.

Comment: Already saw it, but it won't let you control it programaticaly. :(